# difference in constructor usage in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I tried to make a simple implementation of the stack using the class mechanism in c ++, when the program runs everything works as I expected, here is the code prototype

```
class Stack {
private:
   int keep_track {10};
   int * data {};

public:
   // Stack () {
   // data = new int [keep_track];
   //}
   Stack (): data (new int [keep_track]) {}
   ~ Stack () {delete[] data;}
   bool push () {};
   int pop () {};
   int reset () {};
   void print () {};
};
```

My question is, which constructor is used correctly and often in the real world?

Comment: 'Which constructor` out of one choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a class like this:

```
class Stack {
private:
    int keep_track {10};
    int * data {new int[keep_track]};
public:
    ~ Stack () {delete[] data;}
    // ...
};
```

Then you don't need a separate constructor because you have done member-wise initialization of each separate member.  It's the same as having a constructor with an initializer list: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-classes#member-init

If you make a class like this:

```
class Stack {
private:
    int keep_track;
    int * data;
public:
    Stack ()
    : keep_track {10}
    , data {new int[keep_track]}
    {
    }
    ~ Stack () {delete[] data;}
    // ...
};
```

This is exactly the same as the previous example.  The constructor calls the copy constructor of each member in the initializer list - if a member isn't listed and hasn't been already initialized then the default constructor is used.

Each member gets initialized just once in the order the members are listed in the class - not in the order they are specified in the initializer list.

If you make a class like this:

```
class Stack {
private:
    int keep_track;
    int * data;
public:
    Stack () {
        keep_track = 10;
        data = new int [keep_track];
    }
    ~ Stack () {delete[] data;}
    // ...
};
```

Then the default constructor is called for each member because they haven't been initialized and there is no initializer list.  And then the constructor's body calls the assignment operator for each member to set the values.

So each member is done twice.  This is a real problem when one of the members doesn't have a default constructor or can't have a value assigned to it.

If you make a class like the one in your question:

```
class Stack {
private:
    int keep_track {10};
    int * data {};
public:
    Stack (): data (new int [keep_track]) {}
    ~ Stack () {delete[] data;}
    // ...
};
```

Then both `keep_track` and `data` are initialized when the class is created and then the constructor calls the copy constructor again for `data` because it is in the initializer list.

Remember it is important the `keep_track` is declared in the class before `data` because it is the order of declaration that matters and not the order that the constructor does it.

If you make a class like the one in your question:

```
class Stack {
private:
    int keep_track {10};
    int * data {};
public:
    Stack () {
        data = new int [keep_track];
    }
    ~ Stack () {delete[] data;}
    // ...
};
```

Then both `keep_track` and `data` are initialized when the class is created and then the constructor calls the assignment operator again for `data` because it is in the constructor body.

This means data is initialzed twice - in this case it doesn't matter so much because data is just a pointer but, in general, using the initializer list is better.

The method I have seen most is where every member is in the initializer list.  That way it's all in one place and only initialized once - but it is important to keep the order of the initializer list the same as the declaration of the members so that it's clear in what order things happen.  Although I can see real value in initializing the members directly in the class if their values are always fixed, I don't think it is very common yet.